# child elements not displaying when iphone is landscape

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm currently working on a media query css for the iPhone 6 in landscape orientation. I have set up a parent div containing many child elements but not all of them are displaying even though they are all present in the html.

Here is the html

```
<!-- Mobile Content Area -->
<!-- Image Grid -->
<div id="mobile_image_grid_landscape">
    <img src="images/site/spaces_thumbnail.jpg" style="padding-right: 1%" />
    <img src="images/site/foreign_views_thumbnail.jpg" style="padding-left: 1%" />
    <div class="project_title_work_mobile">Title 1</div>
    <div class="project_title_work_mobile">Title 2</div>

    <img src="images/site/white_trails_thumbnail.jpg" style="padding-right: 1%" />
    <img src="images/site/form_thumbnail.jpg" style="padding-left: 1%" />
    <div class="project_title_work_mobile">Title 3</div>
    <div class="project_title_work_mobile">Title 4</div>

    <img src="images/site/mind_and_body_thumbnail.jpg" style="padding-right: 1%" />
    <img src="images/site/moving_image_thumbnail.gif" style="padding-left: 1%" />
    <div class="project_title_work_mobile">Title 5</div>
    <div class="project_title_work_mobile">Title 6</div>

    <img src="images/site/xx_thumbnail.gif" style="padding-right: 1%" />
    <img src="images/site/foreign_views_thumbnail.jpg" style="padding-left: 1%" />
    <div class="project_title_work_mobile">Title 7</div>
    <div class="project_title_work_mobile">Title 8</div>
</div>
<!-- Image Grid -->
<!-- Mobile Content Area -->
```

CSS:

```
/* Landscape */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 667px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape) {
    #mobile_image_grid_landscape {
        visibility: visible;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 11%;
        left: 18.125%;
        width: 63.75%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    #mobile_image_grid_landscape img {
        position: relative;
        width: 49%;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .project_title_work_mobile {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50%;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
}
```

Any advice would be great,
Thankyou

Comment: Where are the media queries?

Comment: @APAD1 I have extracted just the relevant css, I do have it within the file though

Comment: How can we help you with a question about media queries without seeing the media queries? The code you've posted so far seems to work fine (all elements are visible at any size): http://jsfiddle.net/mga5x8to/

Comment: @APAD1 apologies, have added it into the post now. I checked the code within a fiddle too and it also worked although when I preview the site on the device only a couple of the child element appear. Here is a link to the relevant webpage should that be of any help [link](http://www.ashtonjeffreyphotography.com/work.html)

Comment: If site is live, then you can share address.